# Using SQL to SUM Values While Checking and Comparing Values of Other Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

| V1 | I1 | T1 | V2 | I2 | T2 | V3 | I3 | T3 | V4 | I4 | T4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 15 | 1 | 1 | 12 | 1 | 1 | 22 | 1 | 3 |  |  |  |
| 15 | 1 | 1 | 22 | 2 | 3 |  |  |  | 16 | 1 | 1 |
| 15 | 1 | 1 | 15 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | 18 | 2 | 1 |  |  |  |

- V = Value
- I = Indicator
- T = Type

Above I have a table with 4 rows. My goal is to sum together all of the values(V1-V4) of each row where they have a Type(T1-4) of 1 and Indicator(I1-4) of 1 or 2. If a row has a Type of 1 and an indicator 1 and 2 on a line then only one value should be counted. The results from the above table should be:

- Row 1: 27
- Row 2: 31
- Row 3: 15
- Row 4: 18

This was a very easy problem to solve for me until I ran into the issue with the second to last row. I was just doing:

```
 CASE 
    WHEN T1 = 1
      AND I1 = (1 OR 2)
    THEN V1
    ELSE 0
 END +
 CASE 
    WHEN T2 = 1
      AND I2 = (1 OR 2)
    THEN V2
    ELSE 0
 END +
 CASE 
    WHEN T3 = 1
      AND I3 = (1 OR 2)
    THEN V3
    ELSE 0
 END +
```

I just used this logic for the whole table to sum everything together, but learned recently that if a row has an I value of 1 and 2 that only one of the values should be added to the sum.

Is there a way in SQL maybe using a CTE or table variable to figure out a solution here? I am hoping to figure this out just using SQL as there is more to the problem than just this piece and it is already built out in SQL.

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags; [edit] your question to tag correctly.

Comment: `Above I have a table with 3 rows` it seems you have 4 rows. You also have a I value of `12` in the first row. `indicator 1 and 2 on a line then only one value should be counted` which of the values should be counted? You really need to be precise here

Comment: @siggemannen Where is the I value of 12? When a line has an I of 1 and 2 the values will be the same so either one can be counted.

Comment: I am on SQL Server by the way, adding MySQL was a mistake

Comment: You need to provide both sample data and desired results so we can **see** what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: `If a row has a Type of 1 and an indicator 1 and 2 on a line then only one value should be counted.`. ***Which*** should be counted? Highest, lowest, left most, right most, highest indicator, lowest indicator? You need categorical rules that cater for all possibilities, and are deterministic.

Comment: Can the data be restructured? This flat file format is good for humans to read, but bad for sql to process. It "should" be 16 rows of three columns (plus a fourth column to relate batches of four rows back together).  *(9 rows actually, the empty values don't need rows.)*

Comment: @DaleK I provided sample data in the table and the results I am looking for.

Comment: @MatBailie The data can be restructured, this is transactional data so that could be the solution here. However if I broke it into a row for each segment I would also need to account for the indicator 1 and 2 on one line. 
For rows with Type 1 and an indicator 1 and 2 on a line the value can be the left most line.

Comment: On row 2 you allow two instances of (t=1, i=1) to be summed.  Does the same apply to if there are two instances of (t=1, i=2)?  And what should the results be in the following fiddle?  https://dbfiddle.uk/y2QTqpJ8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normalised approach...

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id   INT,
  grp  INT,
  v    INT,
  i    INT,
  t    INT
)
```

```
INSERT INTO
  example
VALUES
  (1,1,    15, 1, 1),
  (1,2,    12, 1, 1),
  (1,3,    22, 1, 3),
  (2,1,    15, 1, 1),
  (2,2,    22, 2, 3),
  (2,4,    16, 1, 1),
  (3,1,    15, 1, 1),
  (3,2,    15, 2, 1),
  (4,3,    18, 2, 1)
```

```
9 rows affected
```

```
WITH
  filtered AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MIN(i) OVER (PARTITION BY id)   AS min_i
  FROM
    example
  WHERE
    t=1
)
SELECT
  id,
  SUM(v)
FROM
  filtered
WHERE
  i = min_i
GROUP BY
  id
```

| id | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 27 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 4 | 18 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/EhoMCCf0)

Answer (score 1):

A brute force approach...

```
CREATE TABLE example (
  id   INT,
  v1   INT,   i1   INT,   t1   INT,
  v2   INT,   i2   INT,   t2   INT,
  v3   INT,   i3   INT,   t3   INT,
  v4   INT,   i4   INT,   t4   INT
)
```

```
INSERT INTO
  example
VALUES
  (1,    15,    1,    1,      12,    1,    1,      22,    1,    3,    NULL, NULL, NULL),
  (2,    15,    1,    1,      22,    2,    3,    NULL, NULL, NULL,      16,    1,    1),
  (3,    15,    1,    1,      15,    2,    1,    NULL, NULL, NULL,    NULL, NULL, NULL),
  (4,  NULL, NULL, NULL,    NULL, NULL, NULL,      18,    2,    1,    NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
SELECT
  id,
  CASE WHEN t1=1 AND i1=min_i THEN v1 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN t2=1 AND i2=min_i THEN v2 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN t3=1 AND i3=min_i THEN v3 ELSE 0 END
  +
  CASE WHEN t4=1 AND i4=min_i THEN v4 ELSE 0 END
FROM
  example
OUTER APPLY
(
  SELECT
    MIN(i1)  AS min_i
  FROM
  (
    SELECT i1 WHERE t1=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i2 WHERE t2=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i3 WHERE t3=1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT i4 WHERE t4=1
  )
    AS pvt
)
  AS indicator_check
```

| id | (No column name) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 27 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 4 | 18 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rC_s6yT5)

Comment: I like this approach and it seems to work without having to manipulate the data, I appreciate your help on this

Comment: @jrdev12345 feel free to upvote / accept answers that help

Answer (score 1):

This approach avoids a sub query.

```
CREATE TABLE tablename 
(
    RowNum INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    V1  int,    I1  int,    T1  int,    V2  int,    I2  int,    T2  int,
    V3  int,    I3  int,    T3  int,    V4  int,    I4  int,    T4  int
);

INSERT INTO tablename (V1, I1, T1, V2, I2, T2, V3, I3, T3, V4, I4, T4) VALUES
    (15, 1, 1, 12, 1, 1, 22, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    (15, 1, 1, 22, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 16, 1, 1),
    (15, 1, 1, 15, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0,  0, 0, 0),
    (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0);

SELECT * FROM tablename

Select RowNum, 
     CASE T1 WHEN 1 THEN CASE WHEN I1 in (1,2) THEN V1 ELSE 0 END
             ELSE 0 END +  
     CASE T2 WHEN 1 THEN CASE WHEN I2 in (1,2) THEN CASE I1+I2 WHEN 3 THEN 0 ELSE V2 END  ELSE 0 END
             ELSE 0 END +  
     CASE T3 WHEN 1 THEN CASE WHEN I3 in (1,2) THEN CASE I1+I2+I3 
                                                    WHEN 3 THEN 0 
                                                    WHEN 5 THEN 0 
                                                    ELSE V3 END ELSE 0 END
             ELSE 0 END +  
     CASE T4 WHEN 1 THEN CASE WHEN I4 in (1,2) THEN CASE I1+I2+I3+I4 
                                              WHEN 3 THEN 0 
                                              WHEN 5 THEN 0   
                                              WHEN 7 THEN 0 
                                              ELSE V4 END ELSE 0 END
             ELSE 0 END   AS SUM
FROM  tablename
WHERE (T1=1 AND I1 in (1,2))
    or (T1=1 AND I2 in (1,2))
  or (T3=1 AND I3 in (1,2))
  or (T4=1 AND I4 in (1,2))
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/N6FdTZw7)

| RowNum | SUM |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 27 |
| 2 | 31 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 4 | 18 |

Comment: Not sure your edit does what you intend : https://dbfiddle.uk/yTYeFTnz

Answer (score 0):

```
CASE 
    WHEN (T1 = 1 
          AND 
          ((T1 = T2 AND I1 <> I2)
        OR (T1 = T3 AND I1 <> I3)
        OR (T1 = T4 AND I1 <> I4)))
    THEN AccumulatorAmount1/2
    WHEN (T1 = 1) 
    THEN AccumulatorAmount1
    ELSE 0
 END +
```

The solution I have found so far is this, but it is messy as instead of making one line a zero I am just dividing an amount by 2 where there is a matching T and a mismatch I. This way summing them together still works, but if the values are odd it does slightly throw off the data.